# I'm in need for a floating point expert

Tags: math, floating-point, ieee-754, logarithm

Can anyone explain to me in detail how this log2 function works:

```
inline float fast_log2 (float val)
{
   int * const    exp_ptr = reinterpret_cast <int *> (&val);
   int            x = *exp_ptr;
   const int      log_2 = ((x >> 23) & 255) - 128;
   x &= ~(255 << 23);
   x += 127 << 23;
   *exp_ptr = x;

   val = ((-1.0f/3) * val + 2) * val - 2.0f/3;   // (1)

   return (val + log_2);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IEEE floats internally have an exponent `E` and a mantissa `M`, each represented as binary integers. The actual value is basically

```
2^E * M
```

Basic logarithmic math says:

```
  log2(2^E * M) 
= log2(2^E) + log2(M)
= E + log2(M)
```

The first part of your code separates `E` and M. The line commented (1) computes `log2(M)` by using a polynomial approximation. The final line adds `E` and the result of the approximation.

Comment: Oh >.<, I fail at reading, please don't kill me! :O, but why is it -128 instead of -127 then?

Comment: Wait! The exponent is expressed as a two complement integer right, hence why theres one more positive number then negative. eh?

Comment: @Skeen: no, I had that wrong and corrected it. As for that offset, I'm not sure. Could actually be a bug in the code.

Comment: @Skeen: yes, it's two's complement, but the bias is still only 127 (according to Wikipedia anyway). It *could* have something to do with the normalized representation where most significant bit of the mantissa is not stored and assumed to be 1.

Comment: @Michael Borgrwardt: it's because the mantissa has an implicit 1 so this gives you an extra power of 2 to take care of.

Answer (score 2):

It's an approximation. It first takes log2 of the exponent directly (trivial to do), then uses an approximation formula for log2 of the mantissa. It then adds these two log2 components to give the final result.

Comment: Okay I can understand how it extracts the exponent and places it in an integer named log_2, and how it extracts the signbit and mantissa and saves it to val though the pointer. What I don't understand is why it works out adding these together.

Comment: And I do understand that once it extracts the signbit and mantissa, it sets exp=127 (0), and therefore the val=signbit*fraction. But how it works out adding that with the log_2, is what really bugs me.

Comment: And really it doesn't extract the exponent, what it does is to extract the exponent -1, as the IEEE 754 is signbit*2^(exp-127)*frac

Comment: @Skeen: OK - that's a subtle point - the mantissa has an implicit 1, so its value ranges from 1.0 to 2.0, so you have one extra power of 2 to take care of.